# How can jest test a function that uses performance.getEntries()?

Tags: javascript, node.js, jestjs

When running jest, if a function makes use of `performance.getEntries` (or `performance.getEntriesByName`) then the test throws an exception:

```
performance.getEntries is not a function
```

How can I allow my tests to continue running without crashing?

---

According to the documentation, `performance.getEntries` was removed from `perf_hooks` in NodeJS v10.0.0 (https://github.com/nodejs/node/pull/19563) and the same functionality may be achieved using

```
const measures = []
const obs = new PerformanceObserver(list => {
  measures.push(...list.getEntries())
  obs.disconnect()
})
obs.observe({entryTypes: ['measure']})
function getEntriesByType(name) {
  return measures
}
```

However the above solution is only viable when working directly in the NodeJS application, not when running tests as I do not want to change my implementation. I have tried mocking `performance.getEntries` as a global in `setupAfterEnv`, as I would for other globals. For example:

```
global.performance = {
  getEntries: () => []
}
```

However when debugging, performance is always equal to `{}` (while `performance.now()` works well. I believe this is default `jsdom` (which is my `testEnvironment`).

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue and was able to resolve it by adding this to my `setupAfterEnv` file:

```
global.performance.getEntries = jest.fn();
```